# LWJGL Shows White Screen after adding lighting

Tags: java, opengl, lwjgl

I am currently working on a game engine using OpenGL using LWJGL in Java. After adding in lighting code a white screen would display for about 2 seconds then the program would stop running with only the following message:

```
Process finished with exit code -1073741819 (0xC0000005)
```

Searching the error brought no results. I just updated by gpu driver just in case that was the problem. I updated my Nvidia driver version to 441.66.

Two of my friends pulled the exact same version of the code from git and the code worked. One used Windows 10 while the other used Linux.

Here is the screenshot from my friend on windows:
[Screenshot of window from friend using windows](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1Oh08.png)

Here is the screenshot from me: [Screenshot of window from my computer](https://i.stack.imgur.com/IGI3W.png)

The code is kinda long so here it is: https://github.com/ryandw11/Test-OpenGL-Engine/

Links to important places in the code can be found here:  [Readme.md](https://github.com/ryandw11/Test-OpenGL-Engine/blob/LightingSystem/README.md)

Information regarding our Libraries can be found in readme linked above.

The master branch works just fine for me while the Lighting System branch does not.
I don't think it is a code issue as it works just fine on the other two computers; however, I am stumped and have no clue how to fix this.

Further Information:
Java Version: 13
I am running the code via Intellij.
Graphics Card: Nvidia Geforce GTX 960.
LWJGL Version: 3.2.3

I am sorry if this is not enough information. This is my first time making a question on here.

Comment: You need to use a debugger.

Comment: @Andrea A debugger as in renderdoc? What kind of debugger?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved this problem. I was not setting the vertex normal uniform and that caused it to not work on the Nvidia gpus.

I solved this problem by using a debugger named [renderdoc](https://renderdoc.org/) on a computer with a different gpu. After setting the normals it proceeded to work on the computer with a Nvidia gpu.